# Why is awk so much faster than python in this case?

Tags: python, awk

I have a clip list with 200,000 rows, each row is of the form

```
<field 1> <field2>
```

In order to get just field 1, I can run a script that looks like this

```
import os
import sys
jump = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
clips = open("clips.list","w")
text = jump.readlines()
list_of_clips = str()

for line in text: 
     clip_to_add =   line.split(" ")[0]
     list_of_clips = list_of_clips + clip_to_add +'\n' 

with open ('clips.list', 'w') as file:
file.write (list_of_clips)

jump.close()
```

or I can just use `awk 'print{($1)}'`

why is awk SO much quicker?  It completes the job in about 1 second.

Comment: Probably because of all the string concatenation in your code, but a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) will show you for sure where the time is being spent. That said, your code is unreadable; please make sure that your code is a [example]. Your code is not reproducible, as it is not syntactically correct Python.

Comment: Please fix your code, it seems to miss several line breaks.

Comment: Because AWK is a low level language optimized for string operations.

Comment: It does everything differently. For starters, no OOP overhead.

Comment: To make something more comparable (though I believe AWK will still come out on top) open both files simultaneously, and as you read and transform a line immediately print it to the other file. As I mentioned above, I suspect a large amount of time is spent on allocating new strings, concatenation of larger and larger strings and garbage-collecting of unused strings: since Python's strings are immutable every `+` creates a new string and has to copy the data from the operands, then assignment back to the variable forgets the previous value of that variable, leaving the string to GC.

Comment: What version of awk (run `awk --version` to check) and what version of python (run `python --version` to check) are you using?

Comment: @timgeb : `awk` is nothing close to low-language at all - for starters bitwise ops offered by `gawk` are encapsulated variants not direct bit level access, you can't determine the endianness of the underlying machine without using external helper utilities because all numeric values are presented to you as "big-endian" equivalent of base-10, non-arrays are passed by value only, and even for arrays, you cannot determine the underlying memory address pointer even though it's passed by reference. `awk` is insanely fast only cuz it, intentionally, doesn't suffer from feature bloat.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto it's much lower level than Python, I think everyone else got the point.

Comment: @timgeb : if anything, it's `python` that's even lower level than `awk`, considering that `python` has direct bit manipulation operators like `^ ~ << | & >>` that `awk` simply lacks

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Python is a slow, high level, general purpose object oriented programming language that does not even have primitive datatypes. You're being intentionally obtuse.

Comment: @timgeb : we can at least agree on the part that `python` is slow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os
import sys
jump = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
clips = open("clips.list","w")
text = jump.readlines()
list_of_clips = str()

for line in text: 
     clip_to_add =   line.split(" ")[0]
     list_of_clips = list_of_clips + clip_to_add +'\n' 

with open ('clips.list', 'w') as file:
file.write (list_of_clips)

jump.close()
```

This code is poorly written from performance point of view. `.readlines()` needs to read whole file to create list (which is mutable, feature which you do not use at all), even despite in your case you do not have to know content of whole file to get processing done. When you are reading file you might use `for line in <filehandle>:` to avoid reading whole file to memory, using this you might `print` first field of SPACE-separated `file.txt` like so

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(" ")[0])
```

Moreover you do `import os` and then do not use any features contained therein and also open `clips.list` twice, once as `clips` later as `file` and then never make any use of former.

To sum it shortly: `awk '{print $1}'` is *correctly* written AWK code whilst presented `python` code is of very dubious quality, comparing them gives unreliable result.